# How to include padding in column width with Susy

Tags: css, grid, susy-compass

```
.main {
   background: green;
   @include span-columns(9,12);
}
```

Is there an easy or inbuilt way in Susy to include , say, a 10px padding inside .main keeping its initial width intact so that the green background doesnt bleed ?

Thanks in advance, and sorry if a version of this question has been asked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Use `box-sizing: border-box;` - this is now [supported by all the major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing), and Compass has a handy `box-sizing()` mixin to take care of prefixes for you. If you [use it everywhere](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) (like I do), it can change the size of a Susy container, but Susy comes with the handy mixin to fix all that for you. Simply add this at the root, before you set your containers - it will set the box model, and let Susy know to adjust for it:

   ```
   @include border-box-sizing;
   ```
2. Use the `$padding` argument ([docs](http://susy.oddbird.net/guides/reference/#ref-span-columns)) to the `span-columns` mixin. With this approach you are limited to the same units you used for declaring your grid - and just like those, these will be converted to fluid values if they aren't fluid already.

You can see why option #1 is way better, as long as you are OK leaving IE7 out of the fun.

Comment: Ahh, I knew I was missing something. I was afraid I would need inner divs for all sections.