# 1px border throwing off SUSY grid

Tags: sass, compass-sass, susy-compass

I'm trying to position two buttons side-by-side using Susy and this seems to work fine:

```
.fifty {
    @include span-columns(3);
    @include nth-omega(2n);
}
```

However as soon as I ad a 1px border to the button the effective width is 100%+4px and thus it breaks the layout.

I'm using the Compass Vertical Rhythm plugin for all my button padding values so would like not to mess that up.

Answer (score 5):

This is related to "[How to include padding in column width with Susy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926593/how-to-include-padding-in-column-width-with-susy/16932494#16932494)", but your second option is a bit different. This problem isn't specific to Susy - it's true of any fluid layout - But Compass and Susy can help you with the first solution:

1. Use box-sizing: border-box; - this is now supported by all the major browsers, and Compass has a handy box-sizing() mixin to take care of prefixes for you. If you use it everywhere (like I do), it can change the size of a Susy container, but Susy comes with the handy mixin to fix all that for you. Simply add this at the root, before you set your containers - it will set the box model, and let Susy know to adjust for it:

   ```
   @include border-box-sizing;
   ```

   Or just use the Compass `box-sizing(border-box)` mixin where you want it (on these buttons).
2. Since borders don't take % values, there is simply no good way to add borders to fluid elements (using the default content-box model). If you can't use the `border-box` model, the only other option is to add an internal element in the markup, use the outer for sizing, and the inner for borders and styles.
3. There is a third option - using `calc()` - but it's harder to do, and has even less browser support...

Option #1 is the best by far - as long as you can leave IE7 out of the fun.